# Perform MS Exchange "Check name" with Python

Tags: python, email, exchange-server, ntlm

I login to our MS Exchange 2003 server via NTLM and can send messages with `smtplib` module. Is there a way to detect my email address (which will be specified in `From:` field of a message) based on NTLM username.

When one adds new Exchange account in Windows it asks for server address and username which can be resolved to an e-mail address (or several addresses if username is ambiguous) with a 'Check name' button. It's done even before logging in to server.

[image: check name button]

Related:

https://github.com/xulz/python-ntlm

[SMTP through Exchange using Integrated Windows Authentication (NTLM) using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916396)

Upd: i think it uses NSPI ambiguous name resolution (ANR), and i also think that spending time on this isn't worth it.)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try and do it with Active Directory using [pyad](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyad):

```
def get_user_email_address(name):
    try:
        from pyad import aduser
        user = aduser.ADUser.from_cn(name)
        return user.get_attribute('mail')
    except e:
        return None
```

Comment: i get `WARN: unable to connect to default domain. Computer is likely not attached to an AD domain` when trying to import `pyad`. Though the PC is   actually connected to a domain.