# Python urlopen windows authentication

Tags: python, windows-authentication

I am not experienced with python and using the below code to open a url and read the response. I am getting an unauthorized error because the site uses Windows Authentication.  Can someone provide a code sample on how to send in the user name and password?

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, params.encode("ASCII"))
html = response.read()
```

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: look here: [windows-authentication-with-python-and-urllib2][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909658/windows-authentication-with-python-and-urllib2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) and [python-ntlm](http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/) Some example code:

```
import urllib2
from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler

user = 'DOMAIN\User'
password = "Password"
url = "http://ntlmprotectedserver/securedfile.html"

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, user, password)
# create the NTLM authentication handler
auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)

# create and install the opener
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_NTLM)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

# retrieve the result
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print(response.read())
```